# I am having a hard time centering a header under an image on my website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a hard time centering the "About Me" header underneath the images of me. I am not very knowledgable in `HTML`/`CSS`/`JS` and googling for a few hours has not helped me. Here is my website: [Click to here](http://people.tamu.edu/~oscargon1234/)

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Thank you, everyone, who helped! Really appreciate it :)))

Comment: Please add some code what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply `text-align` style to make your heading in the center

```
<div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
  <h2 class="heading">About Me</h2>
</div>
```

for about paragraph, add boostrap class `col-md-offset-2` to your column to add margin to center it to the page

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <p>I will be graduating from Texas A&M University at College Station in May 2020 with a BS in chemistry and minors in mathematics and physics. My aspirations are to earn a PhD in chemistry and eventually become a professor at an R1 research university......
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've wrapped your heading to col with same parent row. That is why it is on same row.

Try this out:

```
<div class="row">
  <h2 class="heading">About Me</h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <p>                 
  </p>
    <p>I will be graduating from Texas A&amp;M University at College Station in May 2020 with a BS in chemistry and minors in mathematics and physics. My aspirations are to earn a PhD in chemistry and eventually become a professor at an R1 research university. 
    In addition, I find that participating in mentorship is crucial because as a professor I aspire to not only be a good researcher but also a good teacher. For these reasons I am a mentor for a few organizations, such as the Science Leadership Scholars program and College Scholarship Leadership Access Program (CSLAP). Moreover, I am research advocate and am a undergraduate research ambassador for the LAUNCH office at Texas A&amp;M University.
    In my spare time I enjoy reading fiction, listening to music, and messing with computers.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This did not work unfortunately. My website is updated with the changes you recommended in case you want to see what happens!

Comment: I could see what happens by inspecting it on my browser. It worked in my case because i didnt remove container that wraps it.

Comment: I keep getting the same thing. I updated my webpage with what you told me, do you think you can tell me what I am doing wrong. Sorry if I am being dumb but I am trying to learn as I go. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's already centered. If not, why do you feel it's not centered, more explanation would help us give better answers.

Comment: I want the "About Me" to be centered below the image of me, as well as the text centered underneath the "About Me" header. Not how it appears where the text is adjacent to the "About Me". Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

[image: result]

I did it.

[image: my changes]

```
#about .container .row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

#about > h2.heading {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your About Me in different 'row' and align text to center using style:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;">
                    <h2 class="heading">About Me</h2>
                </div>
    </div>
            <div class="row">
                <p><!-- content here --></p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added about section totally wrong.Remove your code and try this.
Read this bootstrap [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/)

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row" style="text-align: center;">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h2 class="">
                      About Me
                </h2>
           </div>
          <div>
              <div class="">
             <!--About me goes here!-->   
                <p>                 
                </p>
                <p>I will be graduating from Texas A&amp;M University at College Station in May 2020 with a BS in chemistry and minors in mathematics and physics. My aspirations are to earn a PhD in chemistry and eventually become a professor at an R1 research university. 
                  In addition, I find that participating in mentorship is crucial because as a professor I aspire to not only be a good researcher but also a good teacher. For these reasons I am a mentor for a few organizations, such as the Science Leadership Scholars program and College Scholarship Leadership Access Program (CSLAP). Moreover, I am research advocate and am a undergraduate research ambassador for the LAUNCH office at Texas A&amp;M University.
                  In my spare time I enjoy reading fiction, listening to music, and messing with computers.
             
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```